# local variable and global variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

```
1. function add() {
var counter = 0;
    return counter = counter + 1;
}

2. var counter = 0;
function add() {
    return counter = counter + 1;
}
```

Question 1 and 2 getting different result because of counter declared outside and inside. Question 2 adding number 1,2,3,4, etc. But Question 1 it is not happening with adding number. It get stops with 1. May i know why it is adding numbers in question 1.

Comment: counter is reset to 0 each time you call the first one

Comment: @Faruk On question 1, Counter is reset to reset to zero each time. you can check it.

Comment: Every time function initializes counter with value 0 for each call and get result 1

Answer (score 0):

In question 1. whenever function will be call counter will be reset or may be set to 0

```
function add() {
   var counter = 0;// When function will call counter will set to 0
   return counter = counter + 1;
}
```

In question 2: Whenever function will be call variable *counter* will not to set 0 again and you will get incremented result

```
var counter = 0;//Once it will be declare 
function add() {
   return counter = counter + 1;// Counter value increasing when function calling 
}
```